# How to load PyGTK documentation in Eclipse PyDev Plugin in auto-completion?

Tags: python, eclipse, pygtk, pydev, documentation-generation

In Eclipse PyDev plugin, all document of default library of python will be load, but document of pygtk doesn't load in Eclipse.
Any way to load them to eclipse?

Comment: How do you view documentation within Eclipse PyDev in general?

Comment: why I typing method names, pydev autocomplete it, and show the method arguments and with Ctrl+space I can get more information about methods.

Comment: but what does that have to do with documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's your situation, but perhaps you should include pygtk at the forced builtins section of your interpreter properties. Go to the [manual](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html) and check for the forced builtins section.

Look at [this page](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=edit&file=faq23.043.htp) too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your PYTHONPATH includes pygtk.

Comment: I have auto-complete with pygtk, but I need PyDev to show me pygtk methods documentation. can you help me, how to resolve this problem?